Is this discoloration on the wood mold in my attic?
Recently moved to new house and found some black discoloration while poking around in the attic. Is this mold? I did notice it gets pretty hot up there during summer. There is ridge vent and gable fan to vent it. I was recommended by the inspector to install soffit vents for better ventilation. Reading the inspectors note, he only mention that this was dark discoloration due to humidity and could lead to mold but not exactly say this was mold. Can someone tell me if this is mold? if so, how serious? Should i get someone to come and look at asap?








To tell if it is mold or not it has to tested.  Dryness and good ventilation are mold's enemy.  Soffit vents plus ridge vent is very good for ventilation.  You do want vents as low as possible and high as possible.

Looks like there might have been some water getting in at one time or another. That could be the cause of the discoloration. It doesn't look like mold to me, but I'm no mold expert. Personally, I wouldn't worry about it as long as there isn't a continuing moisture issue. If it stays dry, mold can't really grow.

I’m voting to close this question because mold cannot be identified over the internet. A local sample is needed for testing.

Some of the white patches look like mold. With a structure that old, though, it's impossible to say from when.
As long as you don't currently have leaks or poor ventilation it's not really a concern. Mold isn't a death sentence. It's everywhere.
